# Why does one of these code returns True and other returns False for graph patch checking algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

*We need to check if **src** has a path **dst** or not.*

This code returns False:

```py
def has_path(graph, src, dst):
  if src == dst: return True
  for neighbor in graph[src]:
    has_path(graph, neighbor, dst)
  return False
```

This code returns True:

```py
def has_path(graph, src, dst):
  if src == dst: return True

  for neighbor in graph[src]:
    if(has_path(graph, neighbor, dst)):
      return True
  
  return False
```

Comment: The first function code will return 'True' to the calling statement, which does nothing with the returned value, and then it will continue to the 'return False' statement.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet can only return True when `src` and `dst` are equal. In all other cases the loop is executed and after that it returns False, no matter what happens in the loop. More specifically, this code just ignores whatever the recursive call returns. It might as well not make the recursive call and not loop at all. It can be simplified to:

```
def has_path(graph, src, dst):
  return src == dst
```

The second snippet does it right. It does not ignore the boolean that the recursive call returns, and acts on it. If ever the first `return True` is executed (base case), we see that the caller also returns it, and so a `True` value is guaranteed to bubble out of the recursion tree, also preventing any other new recursive call to be made.